# Return Object() from WCF VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF service which has this function:

```
 Public Function ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas() As Object() Implements ISrvConclusionesNotas.ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas
    Dim conclus As New ConclusionesNotasDL
    Return conclus.ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas()
End Function
```

which returns the values specified here:

```
Public Function ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas() As Object()
    Dim objeto(2) As Object
    objeto(0) = ObtenerGruposAnalisis()
    objeto(1) = ObtenerAnalisis()
    objeto(2) = ObtenerConclusionesPredefinidas()
    Return objeto
End Function
```

Each one of this functions returns a List of entities.
If I call this functions individually they return their values ok. But what I want is to make only one call to the service and no several!
I want to be able to receive it in another application like this:

```
Dim concluNotas As SrvConclusionesYNotas.SrvConclusionesNotasClient = New SrvConclusionesYNotas.SrvConclusionesNotasClient
    Dim objeto() As Object = concluNotas.ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas()
```

What should I do?

Do I have to serialize it some way? The process is working great in the service, but in the other app is not receiving the object and I have an exception which suggests this is not supported by http (sending a object array).

Answer (score 2):

WCF only serializes (and deserializes) object types it "knows" about. If your operation returns `Object()`, WCF at that point only knows about `Object()` itself and `Object`. You'll need to indicate to WCF which actual objects can be serialized (and deserialized), by using the `ServiceKnownType` attribute, like in the example below.

```
Public Class StackOverflow_7098691
    Public Class GruposAnalisis
        Public Text As String
    End Class
    Public Class Analisis
        Public Text As String
    End Class
    Public Class ConclusionesPredefinidas
        Public Text As String
    End Class

    <ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface ITest
        <OperationContract()>
        <ServiceKnownType(GetType(GruposAnalisis))>
        <ServiceKnownType(GetType(Analisis))>
        <ServiceKnownType(GetType(ConclusionesPredefinidas))>
        Function ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas() As Object()
    End Interface

    Public Class Service
        Implements ITest

        Public Function ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas() As Object() Implements ITest.ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas
            Dim objeto(2) As Object
            objeto(0) = ObtenerGruposAnalisis()
            objeto(1) = ObtenerAnalisis()
            objeto(2) = ObtenerConclusionesPredefinidas()
            Return objeto
        End Function

        Function ObtenerGruposAnalisis() As GruposAnalisis
            Dim result As GruposAnalisis = New GruposAnalisis()
            result.Text = "GruposAnalisis"
            Return result
        End Function

        Function ObtenerAnalisis() As Analisis
            Dim result As Analisis = New Analisis()
            result.Text = "Analisis"
            Return result
        End Function

        Function ObtenerConclusionesPredefinidas() As ConclusionesPredefinidas
            Dim result As ConclusionesPredefinidas = New ConclusionesPredefinidas()
            result.Text = "ConclusionesPredefinidas"
            Return result
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Shared Sub Test()
        Dim baseAddress As String = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service"
        Dim host As ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(Service), New Uri(baseAddress))
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(ITest), New BasicHttpBinding(), "")
        host.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened")

        Dim factory As ChannelFactory(Of ITest) = New ChannelFactory(Of ITest)(New BasicHttpBinding(), New EndpointAddress(baseAddress))
        Dim proxy As ITest = factory.CreateChannel()

        Dim result = proxy.ObtenerGruposYAnalisisYConclusionesPredefinidas()
        For Each grupo In result
            Console.WriteLine(grupo)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i'm using linq to sql and i added the three <ServiceKnownType(GetType(LINQTOSQLENTITY))> but still not working

Comment: What are the exact types which your service is returning? Also, can you enable tracing at the server? The traces will tell you exactly what type is causing a problem.

Comment: yes i can enable tracing, i'll be honest i've never done that before, i'll investigate it and when i do it, i'll write again. thanks

Comment: You can find information on enabling tracing at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx